# How to fix this error in Spring Boot using Spring Data JPA and MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm try to connect to a MySQL database using Spring Data JPA (in a Spring Boot application) and always the same error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

My `application.properties` looks like:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demographics
spring.datasource.data-username=root
spring.datasource.data-password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I know the `url`, `username` and `password` are good.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with creating connection with the database itself due to authentication.
Execute this with command line or some tool like mysql workbench.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '%root%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY '%root%'
  WITH GRANT OPTION'

I don't think `IDENTIFIED BY` is allowed in `GRANT` queries.

Answer (score 1):

The [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) for "Common Application Properties" states that `spring.datasource.data-username` is *the user to execute DML scripts (if different)*. I think you are looking for:

```
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
```

Notice you don't need the `data-` part of the key.

Keep in mind that if you need different credentials for both, you must specify them accordingly, unless they are the same. Also, just make sure the user have the correct/required privileges to access the schema you are using.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your account in the database does not require password so just put empty password in your property

```
spring.datasource.data-password=
```